# Swap 4 variables without using a temp variable

Tags: c

I want to Swap 4 variables without using a temp variable. Is that possible?

I want to do like `a = b   & b = c  & c = d & d = a`, without using an temp a new 5th variable.

**UPDATE: - ok.. got it! it can't be done without an another new variable!

how can i do it with an single temp variable ?**

Comment: first swap `a`, `b` then `b`, `d` then `c`, `b`....

Comment: I don't understand you updated question.

Comment: @Kay i want to do it atlease using an single temp variable... is that possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [XOR swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) on successive pairs, to swap *n* variables without a temp variable.

```
a b c d   // Variables
-------
A B C D   // Initial values
B A C D   // swap(a,b) 
B C A D   // swap(b,c)
B C D A   // swap(c,d)
```

That said, using a temporary variable is easier to understand, and is not necessarily less efficient.

**EDIT**

Your updated question asks how to swap the variables with a single temporary variable. This is easy.

```
int temp = a;
a = b;
b = c;
c = d;
d = temp;
```

Comment: Where by "not necessarily less efficient" you mean "certainly more efficient".

Comment: That was my guess, but I haven't measured it anywhere.

Comment: @AndyThomas if `c=d` then `c equals to temp that equals to a` :( so its not right!

Comment: @user2925358 - Try the code - it works. It doesn't set "c equals to temp" anywhere. The statement "c = d" copies the *value* of variable d into the *variable* c. The variable c is unaffected by subsequent changes to d. Think of it like four boxes, each holding a page of paper with an integer on it. The statement "c = d" photocopies the page in box d, and puts the copy in box c. Then "d = temp" photocopies the value in temp, and puts the copy in box d.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any Fifth variable , we can work like that if you have 4 variable x, y, z, w and you want to make them x=y, y=z, z=w, w=x.

```
        x=x+y;
        y=x-y;
        x=x-y;

        y=y+z;
        z=y-z;
        y=y-z;

        z=z+w;
        w=z-w;
        z=z-w;
```